# Pdf2DataExtractor is not being resolved. However, I have installed the itext7.Pdf2Data library in my project

Tags: .net, itext7

How to resolve Pdf2DataExtractor?
Pdf2DataExtractor extractor = Pdf2DataExtractor.create(new File("MyFile"));

The reference that are using in my project attached as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctBgQ.png)

I want to resolve the Pdf2DataExtractor, so that I can use its feature.

Answer (score 2):

It usually  happens  when pdf2data is being used within a .NET Core runtime application.

Plese note, pdf2Data needs [.NET framework](https://pdf2data.apryse.com/documentation/docs/engine-guide/root/Native.NetLibrary) to work properly